# Integrating expression with derivatives of two functions with independent variables

Tags: integration

I have a question regarding integration. Consider the expression $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{dg(y)}{dy}$. Is the following solution correct?

$\int \frac{df(x)}{dx} dx = \int \frac{dg(y)}{dy} dx$

$f(x) = x\frac{dg(y)}{dy} + c_1$

$\int \frac{dg(y)}{dy} dy = \int \frac{f(x) - c_1}{x} dy$

$g(y) = (f(x) - c_1) \frac{y}{x} + c_2 = f(x)\frac{y}{x} + \bar{c_1} + c_2$.